# Invalid input datetime

Tags: magento-2.1, datetime

With my magento 2.1.9 i can not save product, because I have an error:

> Invalid input datetime format of value '22/09/2017

I think `Datepiker` reverse month and day, however I have good parameters in catalog settings (custom date : Day / Month / Year) and my user local is fr_FR.

Someone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Kevin, its  Format should be `MM/DD/YYYY`  in data picker Then it will be work

Comment: Thanks but How can i modify it ?

Answer (score 0):

I maked this module to fix, while this error not fixed.

https://github.com/fernandofauth/magento2_datetime